# Do lure modules on multiple Pokestops in your radius stack?

Tags: pokemon-go

So, in my town there are a few areas where multiple Pokestops are in your usable radius at once. If some friends and I use a lure module on one each will the effect stack or is that a waste of modules?

Answer (score 15):

**yes**

We just tested this. The spawn rate for 1 vs 2 vs 3 had obvious increases. Although due to natural variations, we couldn't tell for sure if it was a linear increase or not, but it looked like each stop had its own increased arrival rate of Pokemon.

It also stacks with Incense as well (s.o. Robotnik's comment)

Comment: Which also stacks with Incense as well

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I just camped from a spot with four stops and each with a lure. Each of the stops would generate Pokemon and since there were 4 they kept appearing pretty much non-stop for however long they lasted.

Answer (score 0):

yes at college campuses there are tons of gyms where many people stack lure mdodules X10.

it is excellent.

Also you level determines what pokemon come out and what your already have in your possession.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I know for a fact they increase and I have reason believe the "extra" spawn rates add up, because:

- Pokemon spawn locations are static, if you determine all the spawn locations in your area you will notice spawn never happen too far from them (nor do you get pokemons spawning randomly without buffs)
- Incense spawns a pokemon every 5 (when staying still) or 1 (when moving) per minute.
- If you pay attention what happens when lure are around, you should notice you have an abnormal amount of Pokemon (So based on my area, I found 6-7 instead of 4-6 I always have).
- When catching (most of them) them several times, the usuals respawned somewhat slow (as usual) while extra one(generated by the lure, I assume) respawned every few minutes.

Based on info above I an conclude that normal spawns are not random (you only get a certain amount in an area) and lures actually create more spawn slots around the pokestop.

What that leads me to believe is much like incense generates a spawn slot around you, the lures generate a spawn slot around the pokestop and If i'm right, if you have several lures in your action area, you will just have a proportional number of spawn slots added around you.

Answer (score -1):

I sad next to 2 Lure Modules today and I can tell the Pokemon at the Stops are popping up about every 2-3 minutes when a Module is active. In my case 2 were activated and the Pokemon spawn nearly always at the same second. unlucky for me i only getting Pidgeys and Rattatas or Zubats today at the Spot...
At the Weekend we try this with 2 Modules and Incense.