# Which yields more pokemon - two active lures at once, or two lures used consecutively on one stop?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've been curious about how to optimize my lure usage to get the most bang for my buck - or to ensure I'm not squandering the limited time you get with them, as I don't have availability to play all the time. From [these](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277627/is-it-beneficial-to-layer-lures-on-overlapping-pokestops?noredirect=1#comment390378_277627) [questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273459/do-lure-modules-on-multiple-pokestops-in-your-radius-stack) it's clear that using two lures on two pokestops in range will increase the overall spawn rate. My question is this - is it more efficient to use two lures at once, or keep placing lures consecutively on a single stop?

That is, which technique will yield more pokemon appearances per lure spent, if any difference at all? If I see a lure active on a group of pokestops, should I place another lure next to it or save it for when the first lure runs out?

Comment: From what I've noticed lures just make a pokemon randomly appear at that stop every so often. So whether you have 2 going at once or 1 at a time, you should be catching the same amount of pokemon. 2 at once is obviously faster but if you plan on sticking around awhile or there aren't 2 within range of each other you can do 1 at a time as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using two lures at the same time vs. two lures consecutively should actually yield the same number of pokemon. The only difference is that you might catch a few more if you use the lures consecutively, but that's only because you would have the app open for 30 more minutes.

If you're going to be using a lucky egg as well to get double XP from catches, definitely use two lures on nearby stops. Otherwise, it's really up to personal preference.

Comment: You could argue that putting down 2 lures at once will lure more players than 2 lures used separately...which means you'll get more because more people = more cellular activity = more mons! I can't see any reason to use one after the other instead of just using both, unless you're bored, have only 2 lures left and don't want to spend the second half of an hour doing nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately, while the spawn locations are concentrated near high average cell activity, they don't seem to be correlated with the current cell activity.  As far as I can tell, the spawn locations are fixed, and generate pokemon at a particular minute of each hour.  Drawing more people to the current location will therefore not increase the number of pokemon seen.

Comment: @EldritchCheese this seems to be accurate to my observations and cursory understanding of the data the game uses. In the long term, attracting many players to certain locations over the course of time (days? weeks? months?) may alter spawning patterns in some areas. But in the short term I doubt it has much noticeable effect. At least, currently - it is possible that once the game is fully rolled out globally and the servers are nailed down, they might shift to a more agile method of determining Pokemon spawns.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely get more effect from using lures consecutively, for two reasons:

1) Lures attract pokemon, but they also attract trainers. There is a good chance that another trainer will be drawn to the lure model, and will decide to use their own lure module on the 2nd pokestop.

2) There will be a slight decrease in pokemon caught as the number of consecutive lure models active increases, due to the time taken to catch the pokemon. Particularly if you are bad at throwing, or the pokemon are high CP.

Comment: "Attract Trainers" perfect bait for crime :v

Comment: @NamikazeSheena that already happened

Comment: Both great points! I guess it really just depends on the situation and how confident you are in your catching abilities.